# Error: wsl.exe exited with code 4294967295 on Installing Rancher Desktop

Tags: kubernetes, virtual-machine, windows-subsystem-for-linux, rancher

I am getting the below error when installing the latest stable Rancher Desktop in my Virtual Machine.

Could someone please help?

**Error:**

> Error: wsl.exe exited with code 4294967295

**Command:**

```
wsl --distribution rancher-desktop --exec mkdir -p /mnt/wsl/rancher-desktop/run/data
```

**Logs:**

```
2022-02-02T09:58:39.490Z: Running command wsl --distribution rancher-desktop --exec wslpath -a -u C:\Users\VIVEK~1.NUN\AppData\Local\Temp\rd-distro-gGd3SG\distro.tar...
2022-02-02T09:58:40.641Z: Running command wsl --distribution rancher-desktop --exec tar -cf /mnt/c/Users/VIVEK~1.NUN/AppData/Local/Temp/rd-distro-gGd3SG/distro.tar -C / /bin/busybox /bin/mount /bin/sh /lib /etc/wsl.conf /etc/passwd /etc/rancher /var/lib...
2022-02-02T09:58:42.628Z: Running command wsl --import rancher-desktop-data C:\Users\Vivek.Nuna\AppData\Local\rancher-desktop\distro-data C:\Users\VIVEK~1.NUN\AppData\Local\Temp\rd-distro-gGd3SG\distro.tar --version 2...
2022-02-02T09:58:44.025Z: Running command wsl --distribution rancher-desktop-data --exec /bin/busybox [ ! -d /etc/rancher ]...
2022-02-02T09:58:44.025Z: Running command wsl --distribution rancher-desktop-data --exec /bin/busybox [ ! -d /var/lib ]...
2022-02-02T10:03:54.533Z: Running command wsl --terminate rancher-desktop...
2022-02-02T10:03:54.534Z: Running command wsl --terminate rancher-desktop-data...
2022-02-02T10:03:54.971Z: Running command wsl --distribution rancher-desktop --exec mkdir -p /mnt/wsl/rancher-desktop/run/data...
2022-02-02T10:04:03.418Z: WSL: executing: mkdir -p /mnt/wsl/rancher-desktop/run/data: Error: wsl.exe exited with code 4294967295
```

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I resolved the issue by following steps 4 and 5 here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual#step-4---download-the-linux-kernel-update-package

I found this answer by looking in %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\rancher-desktop\logs\wsl-exec.log which revealed:
"WSL 2 requires an update to its kernel component. For information please visit [https://aka.ms/wsl2kernel"](https://aka.ms/wsl2kernel%22)

Comment: That was also the solution for me on Windows 11, thanks!

Answer (score 39):

I met the same issue in Windows 10.

Below solution helped me:

### 1. Quit Rancher Desktop

[image: Quit Rancher]

### 2. Run below command in Windows command line:

```bash
wsl --update
```

### 3. After update completed, open Rancher Desktop again.

Rancher Desktop works well now.

[image: Rancher Desktop works well now]

After completed installing Rancher desktop, you can use the `docker` and `kubectl` commands in Windows command line successfully.

### References:

[Error: wsl.exe exited with code 4294967295 #1328 - github](https://github.com/rancher-sandbox/rancher-desktop/issues/1328#issuecomment-1022190843)

Comment: @vivek nuna Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 17):

1. Right click Rancher Desktop Icon in Task bar, And Select "Quit Rancher Desktop"
2. Done below in cmd.exe or powershell

```
> wsl --unregister rancher-desktop
> wsl --unregister rancher-desktop-data
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This ominous answer was actually the one that worked for me

Comment: It is quite similar with this comment https://github.com/rancher-sandbox/rancher-desktop/issues/1328#issuecomment-1640538311

Answer (score 2):

In my case :

1.The Virtualization in BIOS was not enabled

2.You can check yours in **Task manager > Performance Tab > CPU Section**

[Task Manager Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmCRD.png)

Once i enabled from BIOS it started working.

Answer (score 1):

You do not necessarily need to update your wsl after updating rancher. You will need to quite Rancher-Desktop and restart it it to make sure kubernates starts again.

Answer (score 0):

to fix this problem in my windows machine, i uninstall all DNS proxy application i have installed before, after that i reset kubernets cluster from rancher desktop. After that all work fine.

Check if you have DNS application like Acrylic in your machine and unistall them, please  let's me known if this solution work for you too.

Hop that help

Answer (score 0):

In my case running:

```
netsh winsock reset
```

command helped.

Answer (score -1):

If you are on windwos system. go to: control panel -> programs and resources. then click at the left "enable disable resources windows", them enable Hyper-V. That is necessary, because kubernetes needs access to VM Vitual Switch.